# How to say that a user has "taken" a reward?

Tags: appropriate

What are the ways of saying that a user has taken a reward?

I need this for a website I'm working on. It offers rewards to users, and they need to select the ones they want. This text will be used throughout the site, on buttons, etc.

I was thinking about the following:

- Claim this reward / Claimed rewards / etc.
- Collect this reward / Collected rewards / etc.

What verb is the most appropriate for use with "rewards"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim your rewards** is pretty standard and acceptable here.

If you're willing to be a little unconventional, you could use **reap your rewards**.

Even though it has a slightly different, idiomatic meaning; I see no reason you can't use it for your website.

Check out this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=claim%20rewards%2Caccept%20rewards%2Ccollect%20rewards%2Creap%20rewards&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclaim%20rewards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccept%20rewards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccollect%20rewards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creap%20rewards%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: And another thanks for that Ngram link, I had no idea about that :D

Comment: @Ivanhoe123: You're welcome. It was here on EL&U I learned of the ngrams myself!